# Transition Matrix involving bases

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the transition matrix from the basis $\{(0,1,2)^T,(1,2,0)^T,(2,0,1)^T\}$
to the basis $\{(9,0,0)^T,(0,9,0)^T,(0,0,9)^T\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I calculated the inverse matrix of $\{(9,0,0)^T,(0,9,0)^T,(0,0,9)^T\}$ and multiplied it by the matrix $\{(0,1,2)^T,(1,2,0)^T,(2,0,1)^T\}$ but my answer was still wrong. I'm assuming i've made an arithmetic error somewhere. Could someone please walk me through this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You are searching a matrix
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&2\\
1&2&0\\
2&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
9&0&0\\
0&9&0\\
0&0&9\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so you have to solve three linear systems with three unknowns. The system for the first row of $M$ is
$$
\begin {cases}
b_1+2c_1=9\\
a_1+2b_1=0\\
2a_1+c_1=0
\end{cases}
$$
that gives the solution $ (a_1,b_1,c_1)=(-2,1,4)$. And you can do the same for the other unknowns.